# Gradle not picking latest version from remote repository( which is s3 )

Tags: jenkins, gradle, amazon-s3

I am having an issue with Gradle.
We have Jenkins Pipeline project which will publish "A" project to S3 repo.
In the same Pipeline we have next step to pickup latest version from S3 repo for Project "A". I also verified S3 it has all latest version published without any issue.

**Problem:**

We are getting old version 5 version back one , lets say 2.8.239 instead 2.8.245(available in S3).

But for other projects it is fine picking latest version. Any suggestions???

**Edited::**

I found  that gradle runs in following order

1. Plugins
2. Configuration Phase
3. Execution Phase

But in Plugin we are trying to read custom extension like " APPConfig{ version }" but not getting right value at that time.
So we are trying to execute that code in task which was created in plugin again.
But we all know that dependencies evaluation happens before task execution. so added some if condition in dependencies script block itself. Now it works.

Comment: it sounds like you use S3 for jar dependency managment?

Comment: yes we use S3 as an artifact repository

Comment: but still due to S3 as artifact repo it is not picking latest .